# How to get number of working days between two dates in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have two dates `Start Date: 2019-08-13` and `End Date: 2019-08-20`.I want the difference of end date to start date in terms of working days(excluding holidays) .so my results would be `4` as `2019-08-15` is a holiday and `2019-08-17`, `2019-08-18` are weekends.

Comment: How do we get the information about the holidays?

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma we have a collection where holidays are stored. Few objects in that collection looks like {date:'2019-08-14',day:Wednesday',holiday:false}  {date:'2019-08-15',day:'Thurseday',holiday:true}

Comment: If that's the collection of holidays, then why ```holiday:false```?

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma in that collection all the dates are stored with holiday flag. But how to achieve the above scenario even if we store holidays only.

Answer (score 5):

try this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$addFields: {days_in_millis: {  $add: [{$subtract: ["$end_date", "$start_date"]}, 86400000] } }},
{$project: {end_date: 1, start_date: 1, millis_range: {$range: [0, "$days_in_millis", 86400000 ] } } },
{$project: {dates_in_between_inclusive: {
    $map: {
        input: "$millis_range",
        as: "millis_count",
        in: {$add: ["$start_date", "$$millis_count"]}
    }
}}},
{$unwind: "$dates_in_between_inclusive"},
{$project: {date: "$dates_in_between_inclusive", is_not_weekend: {
    $cond: {
    if: { $in: [ {$dayOfWeek: "$dates_in_between_inclusive"}, [1, 7] ]},
    then: 0,
    else: 1
}}}},
{$match: {date: {$nin: holidays_dates_list}}},
{$group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    days: {$sum: "$is_not_weekend"}
}}
])
```

Assumptions:

```
1. every document has at least start_date and end_date fields which are mongodb dates.
2. "holidays_dates_list" is an array of dates which has holidays (may or may not include weekends)
```

Above query itself filters weekends. So, "holidays_dates_list" need not have weekends.

Comment: what to do when the holiday calendar is in another collection and i am getting an error {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "$range requires an ending value that can be represented as a 32-bit integer, found value: 1.57248e+10",
 "code" : 34446,
 "codeName" : "Location34446"
} : aggregate failed   when the difference is more.